# Getting the error "Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CrossCore' does not exist in the namespace `Cirrious'

Tags: xamarin, nuget

Getting the error "Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `CrossCore' does not exist in the namespace`Cirrious'. Are you missing an assembly reference?" for PCL. And unable to update packages.

We are getting error when we are trying to update packages in Xamarin studio PCL in Mac machine.  “Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.2.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.”

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating an old MvvmCross project then that is probably why.  Starting with 3.2.1 MvvmCross moved to PCL profile 259.  You'll need to change the profile of your pcl core to this profile or something else that is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstall xamarin by following steps in the url http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/installation/uninstalling_xamarin/

and reinstall the Xamarin Studio, the Nuget packages are started updating.